# Testing acyclicity of simple directed graph

Tags: python-3.x, graph

For testing acyclicity of simple directed graph, I used Depth First Search algorithm. In some test case, my code works well, but sometimes it works incorrectly. Online judge server tells me "In some case, you got incorrect answers.". But I can't know in which case it fails. Test cases are hidden. My code is as follows(written in Python3).

```
def get_graph():
    graph = {}
    numofn, numofe = map(int, input().split())
    for i in range(1, numofn+1):
        graph[i] = []
    for i in range(numofe):
        s, e = map(int, input().split())
        graph[s].append(e)
    return graph

def dfs(v, visited, graph):
    """
    input: current vertex v and list of visited node and graph
    output: if acyclic 0 else 1
    """
    if v in visited:
        return 1
    visited.append(v)
    for next in graph[v]:
        return dfs(next, visited, graph)
    return 0


def test_acyclicity(graph):
    """
    input: graph
    output: 1 if acyclic else -1
    """
    for s in graph.keys():
        if dfs(s, [], graph) == 1:
            return -1
    return 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    N = int(input())
    for i in range(N):
        input()
        graph = get_graph()
        if i == N-1:
            print(test_acyclicity(graph))
        else:
            print(str(test_acyclicity(graph)) + " ", end='')
```

Expected inputs are here.

```
3

2 1
1 2

4 4
4 1
1 2
2 3
3 1

4 3
4 3
3 2
2 1
```

There is 3 test cases(First 3 means "There are 3 test cases."), and follows this format.

```
|V| |E|
(list of non-weighted directed edges)
...
```

Inputs is being hypothesized like this: The Vertexes are [1, 2, 3, .., |E|].

Outputs:

```
1 -1 1
```

So in this case, my program works well. But judge server tells me it fails.

My question is "In which case my program fails?".

---

Postscript

According to Said Sryheni's advice, I fixed my bug in my dfs search.

```
def dfs(v, visited, graph):
    """
    input: current vertex v and list of visited node and graph
    output: if acyclic 0 else 1
    """
    if v in visited:
        return 1
    visited.append(v)
    for next in graph[v]:
        ret = dfs(next, visited, graph)
        if ret == 1:
            return 1
    return 0
```

This works in some small test case, but It always returns in some big test cases(such as the graph has 1000 nodes and 1000 edges).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in python, but in your dfs function, in this line:

```
for next in graph[v]:
    return dfs(next, visited, graph)
```

Wouldn't this return the value of the first child only? I mean imagine the following test case:

```
1
3 3
1 2
1 3
3 1
```

In this case your code will start a DFS from the node with number `1`, go to `2`, see that node number `2` has no more children and return 0. The DFS function at node `1` will return the value 0, instead of completing to run a DFS starting from node `3`, and finding a cycle.

**UPDATE:**
This test case fails on your updated code:

```
1

3 3
1 2
1 3
2 3
```

The correct output is `1`, while your code prints `-1`. Try debugging this test case to find the problem in your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
def dfs(v, visited, graph):
    """
    input: current vertex v and list of visited node and graph
    output: if acyclic 0 else 1
    """
    if v in visited:
        return 1
    visited.append(v)
    for next in graph[v]:
        return dfs(next, visited, graph)
    return 0
```

In the above method, the mistake lies here:

```
if v in visited:
```

Every time, you are traversing the entire list to find out if a node is already visited. This is mostly `O(n)` for every single recursive call of `dfs`. Instead you should maintain a `boolean visited array` so that you can figure out if a node is already visited in `O(1)` time and this should take care of all the inputs.

P.S: Please mark my answer as correct, if it solves your problem.

Comment: I need to send only outputs to the judge server in my case, so it's not a problem about the time complexity.